# How to perform substitution in this "non-paradoxical" Löb Sentence?

Tags: logic

I found [this article/cartoon](https://www.lesswrong.com/posts/ALCnqX6Xx8bpFMZq3/the-cartoon-guide-to-loeb-s-theorem) about Löb's Theorem

> The key to Löb's Theorem is the Löb sentence L .
> L states: "If a proof of L exists, then C".
> C is some arbitrary statement like "1 + 2 = 5".

but

> Direct self-reference is not permitted in Peano Arithmetic. Yet the Löb sentence L apparently refers to L  itself.

so we use this:

> A non-paradoxical version of L in English:
>
> > If the result of substituting "If the result of substituting x for 'x' in x is provable in PA, then C" for 'x' in "If the result of substituting x for 'x' in x is provable in PA, then C" is provable in PA, then C.

When I try to perform the substitution I get

> If the result of substituting "If the result of substituting x for 'x' in x is provable in PA, then C" for '"If the result of substituting x for 'x' in x is provable in PA, then C"' in "If the result of substituting x for 'x' in x is provable in PA, then C" is provable in PA, then C

which looks like I made a mistake.

How is this substitution meant to be performed?